# The proper manner to rebuke?

Tags: commentaries, rebuke-tochacha

Vayikra 19:17 is telling us about rebuking a fellow (someone near to us), the same verse also teach that one condition in order to do this is that one should have no hatefull thoughts of the heart against that person, nor to be revengeful or having anything against the other..
19:18 But one has to love his fellow as he loves hisself (don't do to another, what he wouldn't be liked done to him)...

Is there any example of correct rebuke in the Torah and what do the commentaries say about this?

Comment: The automatically supplied closure reason, "This question does not appear to be about Judaism", is incorrect in this case. The correct reason is: ["Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Learn perek lamed beis of tanya